# How to set value in text view from other Android app

Tags: java, android

I need set value in app instaled in devise from other app or service or broadcast

is for homework...

Example my first app package

```
com.example.example1
```

Second app package

```
com.example.example2
```

My textview id in first app

```
R.id.textView
```

Comment: textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView); in your activity, then call textView.setText("hello world")

Comment: Have you tried anything? You can't just dump requirements on us with no effort shown.

Comment: One of the two apps should feature a ContentProvider.

Comment: i try with broadcast when first application are open but broadcast dont get textview object and set value

Comment: There must be a sender and a receiver.

Answer (score 0):

In your activity of the application that you want you should make a textview like this:

```
textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

Then after you do that in that same application call:

```
textView.setText("Text you want");
```

If that's not what you're looking for then please expand more on what you want to do.

Comment: the textview are in other application package in need create other application to set value from the new application to text view on other application